# Como puedo girar un icono al dar click sobre un botón

Tags: javascript, html, css

como puedo hacer girar un icono al dar click sobre un botón y sobre el mismo icono, el efecto es que cuando de click se muestre como desplegado....hasta el momento llevo la siguiente funcionalidad para mostrar el contenido de una tabla html...se oculta y se desoculta, pero a la par necesito que el icono gire cuando la tabla este desplegada y viceversa

```js
 _goToDesplegable() {
    console.log('btn _goToDesplegable')
    this.expandable = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#bnc-expandable-detail')
    this.expandable.style.display === 'block' ? this.expandable.style.display = 'none' : this.expandable.style.display = 'block';
    this._opened = false;
    this.requestUpdate();
  }
```

```css
.collapsible {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;

}
```

```html
<button class="collapsible"
@click="${this._goToDesplegable}">Detalle<icon  icon="${iconUnfold}" size="26"></icon>
</button>  

<div class="content" id="bnc-expandable-detail"><span>Tabla HTML</span></div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te sugiro añadir/quitar una classe al icono en tu function `goToDesplegable`. Esa classe solo girar el elemento por via de un transform rotate.

```js
this.querySelector('.collapsible > icon').classList.toggle('expanded');
```

```css
icon.expanded {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Comment: Excelente, te lo agradezco mucho....
Saludos.....